# Getting difference between virtual address and Offset in an ELF file

Tags: elf

`readelf -S` of a particular binary gives the following output

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS         0000000000400238  00000238
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 2] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE             0000000000400254  00000254
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 3] .hash             HASH             0000000000400278  00000278
       0000000000000a7c  0000000000000004   A       4     0     8
  [ 4] .dynsym           DYNSYM           0000000000400cf8  00000cf8
.
.
.
```

Difference between virtual address and offset of first section `.interp` is `0x400000`. I am curious as to:

- how is this calculated?
- Is there a programmatic way of determining this?

Comment: This question has an answer here:

https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16841/address-to-file-offset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how is this calculated?

You just calculated it yourself: `0x400238 - 0x238 == 0x400000`. Your question is probably "why is this particular address selected?".

This is the default link-at address for Linux `x86_64` position *dependent* binaries. You can change that address with `-Ttext=...` linker flag. The default is different for `ix86` (32-bit) binaries: it's `0x8048000`.

I am not sure why these particular defaults were chosen.

> Is there a programmatic way of determining this?

Sure: read the `Elf64_Ehdr` from the start of the file. It will tell you offset to the start of program headers (`.e_phoff`). Seek to that offset, and read `Elf64_Phdr`s. Now iterate over them, and their `.p_vaddr` and `.p_offset` will have the same values.

P.S. You are looking at program *sections* which are not used and are not guaranteed to be present in a fully-linked binary. You *should* be looking at program *segments* instead. Use `readelf -Wl a.out` to examine them.